# How can humans improve machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I'm a UX researcher and have begun working on how to improve machine learning models for a new role.

One question I have is how data from humans can be useful for improving a machine learning model. For example, what if I showed the output of an image classification model to human judges and found that it does a terrible job classifying anything that is red (e.g., an apple, a Cardinal, a rose). Since machine learning models have so many parameters and it's probably tough to isolate what parameters are dedicated to color, what could a machine learning engineer fruitfully do with this information?

Does anyone have any resources for problems like this? In essence I want some examples, books, or blogs that might be helpful for me in terms of thinking about collecting data from humans that can lead to insights that machine learning engineers can actually act on to improve models. I'm just not sure where to get started.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may read more on [Human-in-the-loop systems](https://appen.com/blog/human-in-the-loop/).

Comment: It's also closely related to analyzing/understanding the biases included in the training process, in particular the way the training data was built.